# Matlab Error Bars

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add error bars to a matlab scatter plot using the following code:

```
scatter(1:num_episodes, mean(steps_taken));
hold on;
errorbar(1:num_episodes, mean(steps_taken), 5.*ones(1,num_episodes)');
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

However, I was wondering if there was some way of removing the line connecting the points and leaving just the error bars? I looked through the errorbar function's documentation but couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by changing the ErrorBar `LineStyle` property to `none`:

```
h = errorbar(1:num_episodes, mean(steps_taken), 5.*ones(1,num_episodes)');

% >= R2014b
h.LineStyle = 'none';

% Otherwise
set(h, 'LineStyle', 'none');
```